# How to convert date time in standard format

Tags: c#, asp.net

I get date in proper format from the database but i get time in improper format i.e `19/10/2010 4:45:00 AM` . I want  my time to be hh:mm:ss. I am getting only single hour i.e h.
Appending 0 doesnt seem to be a good solution what is an alernative to parse it in expected format i.e hh:mm:ss?

Comment: What code to you have currently?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you try:

```
yourDate.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
```

The uppercase "HH" indicates the 24-hour formatting...

Answer (score 5):

Use `dateTime.ToString("g");`//g - general datetime format.
[Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

or use some custom format: `dateTime.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");`
[Standard Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Pass the right format to the [DateTime.ToString Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tostring%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)  as the following:

```
dateValue.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using *Sql Server* then use

```
Convert(getdate(),varchar(15),109)
```

Details can be found here
[SQL Server Date Time Format](http://www.technoreader.com/SQL-Server-Date-Time-Format.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing "improper" about the date format you are receiving, that is simply the default format for your database (which I believe can be changed by your dba if appropriate)

You want to change the rendered format. You can do this using `DateTime.ToString(string Format)`

```
 DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse("19/10/2010 4:45:00 AM");
 dt.ToString("hh:mm:ss");
```

*Parsing* is how the `DateTime` object reads the existing format to set it's value, `ToString` is about rendering it out.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your problem is. How are you getting a date with improper format from the database? Are you receiving an already formatted `string`?

If so, then you can parse it into a valid `DateTime` using the following:

```
DateTime d = 
    DateTime.ParseExact(date, "dd/MM/yyyy h:mm:ss tt",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

If you already have a `DateTime` then you can format it to a `string` with any of the methods already proposed in the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

yourDate.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");

USE THIS IT WILL WORK.